# return error in front when permissions enable django rest

Tags: javascript, python, django, fetch

I have a view with permission_classes enabled

```
class ProjectCopyView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthor]

class IsAuthor(BasePermission):
    '''Проверка права на авторство проекта'''
    message = "Only the author of the project can share it"

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        try:
            if Project.objects.get(id=view.kwargs['project_id'], user=request.user):
                return True
        except:
            return False
```

This works in postman, but when I try to repeat this request for js the error

```
Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/editor/project/1/copy/' from origin 'null' has been thrown blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Django console gives 401 unautorized

```
async function testSizze(){
const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/editor/project/1/copy/", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Token 8fdc5648e07851c9ebe3c05f56b4c2400f2d90b9"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
    })
});
const json = await res.json();
    console.log(json)
}
```

When i disable permission_classes js the request works

Answer (score 0):

[`fetch` won’t send cookies, unless you set credentials: 'same-origin'.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

```
const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/editor/project/1/copy/", {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Token 8fdc5648e07851c9ebe3c05f56b4c2400f2d90b9"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        "to_user": "admin@mail.ru",
        "permission": ["read"],
        "all_users": "False"
    })
});
```

So maybe you are using the wrong authentication setting for django-rest-framework?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. This project was not developed by me, and I do not quite understand why this is. I added to my permission

```
            if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
            return True
```